# Quarkus REST client - How to configure a different ClientLogger

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

At https://es.quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#logging-traffic it states:

> REST Client Reactive utilizes a default ClientLogger implementation. You can modify this by supplying a custom ClientLogger instance via CDI or when programmatically creating your client.

How can this be achieved through CDI?

I aim to create a ClientLogger that omits logging headers, as bearer tokens are transmitted through them.

Comment: The `ClientLogger` is currently only accesible via the `QuarkusRestClientBuilder`, but I think it makes sense to have a declarative way to register it, so I would propose opening an issue asking for this feature.

Comment: Thanks @geoand, the new issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/38658

Answer (score 0):

From Quarkus 3.9 onwards, simply annotate your `ClientLogger` with either `@Singleton` or `@ApplicationScoped`.

Prior to Quarkus 3.9, additionally include `@Unremovable`.

For more information, refer to [Make ClientLogger beans unremovable](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/38670).